# about Windows Server 2008 OS page file size

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance

I am looking for some documents which analyze whether setting page file size manually (set an initial size and an upper limit) is good or not, and why? Does anyone have any recommended readings?

Setting page file size manually I mean -- change the setting by select my computer -> properties -> advanced -> settings -> advanced -> virtual memory -> total page file size for virtual memory on all drives -> disable letting system automatic manage, and manually set its initial size and upper limit.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889654) link from microsoft gives advice on the size of a pagefile for 64-bit versions of windows. The information provided does not say it is for win2k8 but the same things should apply. This document should help get you started.

For what it is worth, on any windows server we setup that is actully going to see a decent amount of use we manually set our pagefile sizes.

Comment: Which link do you mean?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889654

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Vista/2008/7/2008R2 let Windows set the Page File size automatically unless you have a *really* good reason to change it. Microsoft has put plenty of man-hours into fine tuning it, they know what they're doing.

Comment: Hi Chris, do you have any document from Microsoft to prove that automatically managed size is preferred?